# Chef Minitest to check the content of a file

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, chef-infra, minitest

I would like to check the content of a file in my chef minitest.

Example File:

```
THIS IS A TEST
#################
## DO NOT FIND ##
#################
FIND THIS 
AND THIS
```

Now I want to verify the content of this file. I used [default_test.rb](https://github.com/calavera/minitest-chef-handler/blob/master/examples/spec_examples/files/default/tests/minitest/default_test.rb) has an example, and am currently doing the following:

```
# = Checking file content =

it "will check the file" do
  file('/tmp/foo')
   .must_include 'THIS IS A TEST'
  file('/tmp/foo')
   .must_include 'FIND THIS'
  file('/tmp/foo')
   .must_include 'FIND THIS'
end
```

There has got to be a better and cleaner solutions, than chaining it like so. Anyone know?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cycle.

```
it "has the rights lines in /tmp/foo" do
  ['THIS IS A TEST', 'FIND THIS', 'AND THIS'].each do |line|
    file('/tmp/foo').must_include line
  end
end
```